# Kotlin Dagger2 cannot find symbol ApplicationModule_ProvideApplicationFactory

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm trying to use Dagger2 with Kotlin but today trying to compile got this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> Error:(5, 43) error: cannot find symbol class ApplicationModule_ProvideApplicationFactory

**(App) Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ilyarb.geotags"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    }
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

    final SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION = "23.3.0"
    final PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION = "8.4.0"

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"

    // Dagger 2
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.2'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2'
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION"

    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.byteunits:byteunits:0.9.1'

    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.3.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.1-2'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
}
```

**root build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Application class**

```
package com.ilyarb.geotags

import android.app.Application
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient
import com.ilyarb.geotags.injection.component.ApplicationComponent
import com.ilyarb.geotags.injection.component.DaggerApplicationComponent
import com.ilyarb.geotags.injection.module.ApplicationModule
import com.squareup.leakcanary.LeakCanary
import timber.log.Timber
import javax.inject.Inject

class GeotagApp : Application() {

    @Inject lateinit var mGoogleApiClient: GoogleApiClient

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic lateinit var mApplicationComponent: ApplicationComponent
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        LeakCanary.install(this)

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
        }

        mApplicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
            .applicationModule(ApplicationModule(this))
            .build()

        mApplicationComponent.inject(this)
    }

}
```

**Application Component**

```
package com.ilyarb.geotags.injection.component

import android.app.Application
import com.ilyarb.geotags.injection.module.ApplicationModule
import dagger.Component
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(ApplicationModule::class))
interface ApplicationComponent {

    fun inject(application: Application)

}
```

**Application Module**

```
package com.ilyarb.geotags.injection.module

import android.app.Application
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
class ApplicationModule(private val mApplication: Application) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideGoogleApiClient() : GoogleApiClient {
        return GoogleApiClient.Builder(mApplication)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build()
    }

}
```

It generates DaggerApplicationComponent but when i try to run application it fails with this error.

I've already tried to clean and rebuild the project but it didn't work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ilia, maybe you can create sample project on github, it's will really help people to answer on your question.

Comment: @IRus i have a project that has a same error [link](https://github.com/ilya-rb/Photo-Map).

I already tried to create a new project and make it work, but still same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through your project I noticed some of your dagger `Module`s have providing methods with similar names like `providesContext()`. Dagger 2 (or kapt) may have a problem with it, which results in your error. Please try renaming them, so that all `@Provides` methods have unique names.

Also annotations have the runtime retention in Kotlin by default, so you don't need to use `@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)`.